# Highchart navigator data format

Tags: mysql, datetime, highcharts

I used MySQL data field in datetime type for the x-axis of a highchart. Actual data as follows:

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00,
2015-01-01 00:01:00,
2015-01-01 00:02:00,
2015-01-01 00:03:00,
2015-01-01 00:04:00,
2015-01-01 00:05:00
```

No of records started from 2015-01-01 00:00:00 to 2015-12-31 23:59:00 in the table.

The chart created successfully. But the navigator shows figures as follows:

1 Jan, 00:00:00:005, ..., 00:00:00:025 and so on

[image: Navigator]

But I want to show actual data in the navigator. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can any one help me solve this?

@ Nate Barbettini. No. the x-axis is showing correctly. The problems is in the navigator. Hereby includes the image of the chart as follows:

[image]

Comment: Including a minimal demo would help solve the issue.

Comment: Please include a JSFiddle or sample of how your complete `data` array looks.

Comment: Pls. use this link http://jsfiddle.net/wgmjs/1v46wqd8/

Comment: That is PHP; it won't work in a fiddle. We need to see your JS code.

Comment: Added in the fiddle. Use this link http://jsfiddle.net/wgmjs/8ebdt74d/

Answer (score 0):

The [minRange property](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange) lets you control the minimum interval the axis displays. From the docs:

> For example, for a datetime axis the main unit is milliseconds. If minRange is set to 3600000, you can't zoom in more than to one hour.

That sounds to me what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were using Highstock. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630554/highstock-minimal-zoom

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are using categories on xAxis. In general, Highstock doesn't support `xAxis.type` other than `datetime`. Of course, you can set categories, just to allow users use that option on their own risk.

Solution in steps:

- remove categories
- for each point use `[timestamp, value]` or `{x: timestamp, y: value}` format

Note, that x-value need to be **timestamp**, not date string, or date object.

Comment: 1) Remove categories - it's quite obvious. 2) Your format is probably like this: `[12, 23, 24, 25 .. ]`, change this to `[ [1423564435333, 12], [1423564490000, 23], [1423564500000, 24] ... ]`. If you create working jsFiddle I can help you more, but this should be enough.